# How to Connect Template Items and Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I want to create a chat box with rails. I have a template for the chat box.

```
      ...
      <div class="messages">
          <div class="messages-content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="message-box">
          <textarea type="text" class="message-input" placeholder="Type message..."></textarea>
          <button type="submit" class="message-submit">Send</button>
      </div>
      ...
```

I've created controllers but I don't know how to establish a relation between rails controllers and template items (button, message text etc.).

Could you help me?

Comment: Why you need the relation between template and controller??

Comment: I'm sorry that I couldn't clarified. How can I record messages to my database? There is no relation between my template and rails controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are developing chat application, [faye](https://github.com/jamesotron/faye-rails) is the good solution out there.

And if you want to create it of your own use [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/create-a-chat-app-with-rails-5-actioncable-and-devise/) beginner tutorial

It covers all important aspects of chat application.